# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' where name_id in (' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my stored procedure I am using dynamic query . I am passing parameter `@nameid int`

The where statement is throwing error .

```
@strWhere = ' where name_id in ('+@nameid+') and timeid=10'
```

Error

**Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' where name_id in (' to data type int.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@strWhere = ' where name_id in ('+ cast(@nameid as varchar) +') and timeid=10'
```

Comment: why is it so , name_id column is of datatype int .

Comment: `int` is not `string`. You have to cast the number to a string. Then you can put together the 2 strings. SQL Server does not automatically turn the number into a string to add them. They are 2 different types you are trying to add.

Comment: @mhasan - maybe the *column* is of type `int`, but at this moment you are just trying to create a string. When you use the `+`operator SqlServer doesn't automatically convert the int (`@nameid`) to string but rather tries the opposite: convert the string literals to int. Which is where the error comes from.